# How to Identify Cells by Italic Formatting?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am putting together a sheet of F1 results over the years.

On Wikipedia the fastest laps are denoted by italicized numbers.

When I copy and paste I want to count all cells in the range that are italicized and between the value of 1 and 10.

Here is what I am currently trying.

```
Sub COUNIFItalics()
Public Function Count_Italic ("A3:Y3 as Range") As Long
Dim Cel As Range
Application.Volatile
For Each Cel In Rng
    If Cel.Font.Italic = True Then
         Count_Italic = Count_Italic + 1
    End If
Next Cel
End Sub
```

This is trying to count by italics so any help with the "1 is less than or equal to x is less than or equal to 10" part would be amazing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you want a UDF and use it like a formula.

What you are missing is 2 more `If`s to check if the value is `equal or more than 1` and `equal or less than 10` (or in this case, I use `Select` statement instead):

```
Public Function Count_Italic(inputRng As Range) As Long
    Dim Cel As Range
    Application.Volatile
    For Each Cel In inputRng
        If Cel.Font.Italic = True Then
            Select Case Cel.Value
                Case 1 To 10: Count_Italic = Count_Italic + 1
            End Select
        End If
    Next Cel
End Function
```